# Actionscript Loader event not firing in Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, actionscript, flash-cs5

I was wondering if someone could help, as I am not much of an actionscript guru.

I just inherited some code that produces an embedded rdio music player into a swf. It works great in firefox and safari, except the embedded player does not appear in Firefox... :(

Is this a common issue with the Loader class or contentLoaderInfo events?

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


flash.system.Security.allowDomain('rd.io');
flash.system.Security.allowDomain('rdio.com');


/* AD SPECIFIC VARIABLES */

var loader_url:String = 'http://rd.io/e/QUzrrjNWMC8/220/500/';
var loader_x:int = 40;
var loader_y:int = 50;


/* RDIO EMBED */


stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load( new URLRequest(loader_url) );
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderDone);
var sprite:Sprite = this;
function loaderDone(event: Event):void
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderDone);
    loader.x = loader_x;
    loader.y = loader_y;
    sprite.addChild(loader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that the event is not firing?

My initial thought is that this isn't a Flash issue at all, but rather a CSS issue. Make sure your Flash content isn't being hidden by the CSS, such as a CSS reset sheet.

I know of no browser specific issues to do with either Loader or contentLoaderInfo. Based on experience, I really doubt that is where your issue lies.

You can add these other events to try and diagnose an AS3 bug:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, unLoadHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Its not a css issue as it works in other browsers, and the swf loads always loads, but the embedded rdio player does not appear in firefox. 

I am not totally sure that the event is not firing, however I am kind of clueless as to what else the issue could be.

Comment: So in Firefox you see the parent SWF but not the child? Make sure you listen for both IO Errors and security errors, if complete is not firing, one of those events will be.

Comment: Thanks again!! Yes that is correct. In Firefox I see the container (parent SWF) but not the embedded rdio player. Okay, cool. do you have an example of how I might add those listening events to my code? I am not ultra experienced in actionscript.

Comment: Sure, see the edited answer. To debug in the browser, try adding a visual message to the stage when one of these events fire.

Comment: awesome, thanks. I have since discovered Firebug in Firefox is telling me that rd.io is giving a 403 error.... would this mean that it might be something to do with the rdio player?

http://200okay.com/test/rdio_300x600-fffix.swf

Comment: Yes, 403 means forbidden. Perhaps because you're not logged in to their site in Firefox? Regardless, its not a Flash issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always listen for errors or exceptions

   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
2. Call the load() function after listening to events. (not sure if make too much of a difference but this is a good programming practice)

   var loader:Loader = new Loader();
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderDone);
   loader.load( new URLRequest(loader_url) );

Answer (score 0):

This link might help, complete event sometimes does not play on firefox.
http://numiko.com/labs/2009/12/flash-event-complete-sometimes-doesnt-fire-in-firefox/